# Flask app loading for long time after added selection coding

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

In the coding below, I'm using a responsive dropdown menu for job field and job title and I'm trying to display dynamic content based on which menu item is chosen. I want to display from content in CSV file, where I will have three CSV files, job_it.csv, job_dm.csv, and job_fn.csv. For each CSV file, it contains 4 rows: header(title, location, education, skills, languages, certification, and years experience), job title 1, job title 2, and job title 3. Then, I already create upload page where the user can select what field they want and the title for each field. After clicking the button, it will display the contents from the CSV file on the next page where if they select first title, the page will the display only the second row (row with title 1).

Here my coding for the flask app. Before I add the code of if-elif coding, the file working fine. But, after add some lines for the selection, the page is loading and didn't appear my home page. How to optimize and solve this problem?

```
import csv

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import pandas as pd
from scraper import scrape_data
from data_cleaning import clean_data

app = Flask(__name__)
app.static_folder = 'static'

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home_page.html')

@app.route('/upload_page')
def upload_page():
    return render_template('upload_page.html')

# @app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
# def process():
#    job_field = request.form['job_field']
#    return redirect(url_for('display', job_field=job_field))

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    job_field = request.form['job-field']
    job_title = request.form['job-title']

    if job_field == "Information Technology and Software Development":
        if job_title == "Senior Frontend Developer":
            with open('static/job_IT.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
                next(reader)  # skip the header row
                jobdata = []
                for i, row in enumerate(reader):
                    if i == 1:  # append the second row to the data list
                        jobdata.append(row)
                        break  # stop reading the file
        elif job_title == "Data Processing Specialist":
            with open('static/job_IT.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
                next(reader)  # skip the header row
                jobdata = []
                for i, row in enumerate(reader):
                    if i == 2:  # append the second row to the data list
                        jobdata.append(row)
                        break  # stop reading the file
        elif job_title == "Java Developer":
            with open('static/job_IT.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
                next(reader)  # skip the header row
                jobdata = []
                for i, row in enumerate(reader):
                    if i == 3:  # append the second row to the data list
                        jobdata.append(row)
                        break  # stop reading the file
    elif job_field == "Digital Marketing":
        if job_title == "Digital Marketing Web Specialist":
            with open('static/job_DM.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
                next(reader)  # skip the header row
                jobdata = []
                for i, row in enumerate(reader):
                    if i == 1:  # append the second row to the data list
                        jobdata.append(row)
                        break  # stop reading the file
        elif job_title == "Video Editor":
            with open('static/job_DM.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
                next(reader)  # skip the header row
                jobdata = []
                for i, row in enumerate(reader):
                    if i == 2:  # append the second row to the data list
                        jobdata.append(row)
                        break  # stop reading the file
        elif job_title == "Graphic Designer":
            with open('static/job_DM.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
                next(reader)  # skip the header row
                jobdata = []
                for i, row in enumerate(reader):
                    if i == 3:  # append the second row to the data list
                        jobdata.append(row)
                        break  # stop reading the file
    elif job_field == "Finance":
        if job_title == "Financial Analyst-SSC":
            with open('static/job_FN.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
                next(reader)  # skip the header row
                jobdata = []
                for i, row in enumerate(reader):
                    if i == 1:  # append the second row to the data list
                        jobdata.append(row)
                        break  # stop reading the file
        elif job_title == "Accountant":
            with open('static/job_FN.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
                next(reader)  # skip the header row
                jobdata = []
                for i, row in enumerate(reader):
                    if i == 2:  # append the second row to the data list
                        jobdata.append(row)
                        break  # stop reading the file
        elif job_title == "Specialist, Business Finance (APAC)":
            with open('static/job_FN.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
                next(reader)  # skip the header row
                jobdata = []
                for i, row in enumerate(reader):
                    if i == 3:  # append the second row to the data list
                        jobdata.append(row)
                        break  # stop reading the file

    file = request.files['file']
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    data = scrape_data(df)
    cleandata = clean_data(data)
    print(cleandata)
    return render_template('display.html', data=cleandata, jobdata=jobdata)

# @app.route('/classify_data', methods=['POST'])
# def process_data():
    # Process data here
#    return render_template('display_classification.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```